# Playsound 1.2.2 parameter block=False disables sound

Tags: batch-file, ipython, playsound

I'm using Python 3.9.7 and playsound 1.2.2 (as latest version had issues). When parameter `block=False`, there's no sound and the script executed without any error. I tried both *.mp3 and *.wav file.
How to make the parameter `block=False` work with sound? It enables my script to continue running without waiting for the mp3 to finish playing.

**New discovery: apparently `block=False` worked when script is run in IPython console but not in a terminal. How to make it work through batch file?

python script (test.py):

```
from playsound import playsound
# playsound("myfile.mp3")    # work fine with sound
playsound("myfile.mp3", block=False)   # execute without error but no sound
```

batch file:

```
set root=D:\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
%root%\python.exe "D:\test.py"
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more on IPython console and some trial & error, found a working solution which is modify the batch file to run the script using Anaconda's ipython.exe located in the Anaconda3/Scripts directory:

```
set root=D:\Anaconda3 
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root% 
%root%\Scripts\ipython.exe -i "D:\test.py" 
pause
```